# Maximum hard drive capacity that can be used in laptop

Tags: hard-drive

Is there any way to determine what the maximum capacity hard drive is that I can use in my laptop?

Comment: What can restrict HDD capacity?

Comment: The mainboard can restrict it as it specifies standards and other things. What laptop are we talking about? Are we talking internal HDD? The largest 2.5" SATA drive is 1 GB.

Comment: I am using Toshiba Satellite A100, installed HDD is 80GB now I wish to replace it with new Segate 500GB HDD. Yes we talking internal HDD.

Comment: @MikeEast 1GB? or 1TB?.....

Comment: sorry, i cann't get you. I just want to replace my 80 GB HD with new 500 GB (not 1GB or 1TB).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nearest limit you have to worry about is the 2TB MBR limit. 500GB should be no problem. Make sure that the hard drive you want to purchase is the same type (IDE/SATA) as the one you're replacing.

Comment: ok, can I use SATA I or SATA II any. Ofcourse my laptop has SATA HDD.

Comment: It should be no problem, then. Once you need capacity over 2.19TB, however, you'll need to upgrade your computer and move to an OS beyond Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

This [easy upgrade site](https://www.drivesolutions.com/upgrade/) will tell you all your options for upgrading your laptop hard drive and memory.  Just select make, series, model.  They will offer to sell you the drive but you can just use the information and shop around.